how to correctly place an image in a doc
Even though I put the necessary latex code for the image in the appropriate location, I wanted to insert the following image at the conclusion of the issue statement, but it ended up at the top of the second column.

relevant code section:
...
\section{Problem Statement}

The challenge in Type 1 Diabetes management is to design an RL-based algorithm that can autonomously regulate blood glucose levels by determining the optimal insulin delivery rates at various times. This algorithm must not only achieve precise glucose control but also ensure safety. This involves:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item {\bf Developing an RL algorithm } that can effectively learn and adapt to the dynamics of a patient’s glucose-insulin response with high accuracy.
  \item {\bf Ensuring safety } by incorporating mechanisms that prevent hypo- and hyperglycemic events during glucose regulation. Current available algorithms do not explicitly address issues in patients’ safety, especially hypoglycemia.
\end{enumerate}

The primary goal is to improve RL's capabilities to automate insulin delivery through a closed-loop system that dynamically adjusts to the patient's varying insulin needs while ensuring the patient is in a safe region while getting the insulin treatments.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{Main_components_of_an_Artificial_Pancreas_Systems}
    \caption{Main components of an Artificial Pancreas Systems (APS)}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\section{Motivation}
...

Although I tried with \FloatBarrier from placeins it didn't work out.
So I need help to get this image to the end of Problem Statement section, so the image should go somehow to the center of the second column not the top of it

Note: The default placement of figures in the standard classes or the KOMA-Script classes and several others is tbp (top, bottom, page). But it seems you want also h (here). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat for more information about placement options. For non-floating see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text. BTW: Don't use [tag:overleaf] for general LaTeX questions, but only for overleaf specific problems.

Try with
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

...
\section{Problem Statement}

The challenge in Type 1 Diabetes management is to design an RL-based algorithm that can autonomously regulate blood glucose levels by determining the optimal insulin delivery rates at various times. This algorithm must not only achieve precise glucose control but also ensure safety. This involves:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item {\bf Developing an RL algorithm } that can effectively learn and adapt to the dynamics of a patient’s glucose-insulin response with high accuracy.
  \item {\bf Ensuring safety } by incorporating mechanisms that prevent hypo- and hyperglycemic events during glucose regulation. Current available algorithms do not explicitly address issues in patients’ safety, especially hypoglycemia.
\end{enumerate}

The primary goal is to improve RL's capabilities to automate insulin delivery through a closed-loop system that dynamically adjusts to the patient's varying insulin needs while ensuring the patient is in a safe region while getting the insulin treatments.


\bigskip
\includegraphics{....}
\captionof{figure}{...caption text...}
\bigskip

\section{Motivation}
...

